Troubleshooting Table Recognition in Images Using Google Vision API

I'm working on recognizing tables within images using the Google Vision API. However, I'm encountering an issue where the API groups together the colored sections, making it unable to recognize individual lines of text. I've tried various approaches like detecting RGB 255, 255, 255 to segment the tables and even experimented with template recognition using multiple sample images, but the results are inconsistent. I'm unsure of the best way to proceed. Can you suggest a direction for me? Any guidance would be appreciated.
Attempted to detect RGB 255, 255, 255 to segment the tables
Experimented with template recognition using multiple sample images.
